# Multiple definition of CUDA device functions

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to compile some functions to use them in host code and in device cuda code but I'm getting a multiple definition linking error. 
What Im trying to achieve is the following:

I have a CudaConfig.h file with the following content

CudaConfig.h

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_DEVICE __device__
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_HOST __host__
#define CUDA_CALLABLE __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_DEVICE
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_HOST
#define CUDA_CALLABLE
#endif
```

In my foo.h file I have some functions with the following signature

```
#include "CudaConfig.h"
struct Bar {Eigen::Vector3d v;};
CUDA_CALLABLE_DEVICE Eigen::Vector3d &foo(Bar &aBar);
```

and I implement them in foo.cpp and a foo.cu files.

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

Eigen::Vector3d &foo(Bar &aBar) {aBar.v += {1,1,1}; return aBar.v;}
```

foo.cu

```
#include "foo.h"

Eigen::Vector3d &foo(Bar &aBar) {aBar.v += {1,1,1}; return aBar.v;}
```

I need to separate both implementations in different files as Eigen disables some SIMD operations when you use it from a `__device__` function, so I dont want to implement both in foo.cu file for performance reasons.

Should I implement the function directly in the .h file, marking them as inline so I dont have the multiple definition linking error? As Eigen disables the SIMD for the `__device__` code, wouldn't this make the `__host__` and `__device__` functions different unlike what inline expects?

Comment: I doubt you can do this. The language and toolchain don't allow different implementations of a given function in host and device code. Your only solution is probably to use a template tag to differentiate them

Comment: I have decided to go that way. I have put device ones in a cuda namespace. Thanks

Comment: " need to separate both implementations in different files as Eigen disables some SIMD operations when you use it from a \_\_device__ function" <- The first part of the sentence does not follow from the second part.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening:

```
rthoni@rthoni-lt1:~/projects/nvidia/test_device_host$ cat test.cu
extern "C" {
__device__ void test_device_fn()
{
}
}
rthoni@rthoni-lt1:~/projects/nvidia/test_device_host$ nvcc test.cu -c -o test_cu.o
rthoni@rthoni-lt1:~/projects/nvidia/test_device_host$ objdump -t test_cu.o 

test_cu.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 tmpxft_000004d9_00000000-5_test.cudafe1.cpp
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l     O .bss   0000000000000001 _ZL22__nv_inited_managed_rt
0000000000000008 l     O .bss   0000000000000008 _ZL32__nv_fatbinhandle_for_managed_rt
0000000000000000 l     F .text  0000000000000016 _ZL37__nv_save_fatbinhandle_for_managed_rtPPv
0000000000000010 l     O .bss   0000000000000008 _ZZL22____nv_dummy_param_refPvE5__ref
000000000000002f l     F .text  0000000000000016 _ZL22____nv_dummy_param_refPv
0000000000000000 l    d  __nv_module_id 0000000000000000 __nv_module_id
0000000000000000 l     O __nv_module_id 000000000000000f _ZL15__module_id_str
0000000000000018 l     O .bss   0000000000000008 _ZL20__cudaFatCubinHandle
0000000000000045 l     F .text  0000000000000022 _ZL26__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtilv
0000000000000067 l     F .text  000000000000001a _ZL32__nv_init_managed_rt_with_modulePPv
0000000000000000 l    d  .nv_fatbin 0000000000000000 .nv_fatbin
0000000000000000 l       .nv_fatbin 0000000000000000 fatbinData
0000000000000000 l    d  .nvFatBinSegment   0000000000000000 .nvFatBinSegment
0000000000000000 l     O .nvFatBinSegment   0000000000000018 _ZL15__fatDeviceText
0000000000000020 l     O .bss   0000000000000008 _ZZL31__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallbackPPvE5__ref
0000000000000081 l     F .text  0000000000000026 _ZL31__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallbackPPv
00000000000000a7 l     F .text  0000000000000045 _ZL24__sti____cudaRegisterAllv
0000000000000000 l    d  .init_array    0000000000000000 .init_array
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000016 g     F .text  0000000000000019 test_device_fn
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 exit
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 __cudaUnregisterFatBinary
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 __cudaInitModule
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 __cudaRegisterFatBinary
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 atexit
```

As you can see, even though the function is tagged as `__device__` only, `nvcc` will still generate a symbol for it in the object file.

**This behavior is a bug of `nvcc`.** (#845649 in our bug tracker)

There's 3 ways of getting rid of this error:

- Let `nvcc` generate both device and host code
- Change the way you compile `cu` files to just build device code
- Wrap your `__device__` function in an empty namespace

Comment: How can nvcc be building the `__host__` function if its only marked as `__device__`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mis read the macro in the header. Anyway, nvcc is still generating a symbol in host code, and that's the problem. I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Got an answer from compiler team: this is a bug in nvcc. I'm editing the answer to add this piece of information

Comment: This answer still doesn't seem to make sense the way it's phrased right now. Why would nvcc define a symbol for a host function that's not declared?

Comment: Yeah true, I removed the first part and added some explanations

Comment: So nvcc still exports symbols from .cu files to all other files? I'm having trouble where a `__device__` function define in two separate compilation units (but not declared to each other) generates multiple definitions errors.

Comment: No, it will only impact the current source/object file. In the previous example, `nvcc` is generating a symbol for the device function `test_device_fn` in the `test_cu.o ` object file (that is the bug). This will cause trouble at link time if you define a CPU side `test_device_fn` function in another file, because the linker will find twice the same symbol.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case it looks like you can just make it a `constexpr` undecorated function:

```
constexpr Eigen::Vector3d &foo(Bar &aBar) noexcept {aBar.v += {1,1,1}; return aBar.v;}
```

and invoke `nvcc` with `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`:

```
--expt-relaxed-constexpr                   (-expt-relaxed-constexpr)       
        Experimental flag: Allow host code to invoke __device__ constexpr functions,
        and device code to invoke __host__ constexpr functions.Note that the behavior
        of this flag may change in future compiler releases.
```

this should work for both device and host code.